# Need a sample code to use google calendar in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-calendar-api

Please tell me how to use google calendar in asp.net. i needs a sample code for scheduling in google calendar using asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See following
http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html

Comment: well thanks dear, i got guide their. but i need a starter kit of it. a small running sample.